# 'MultiOutputClassifier' object is not iterable when creating a Pipeline (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I want to create a pipeline that continues encoding, scaling then the xgboost classifier for multilabel problem.
The code block;

```
# Create a boolean mask for categorical columns
categorical_columns = X.columns[X.dtypes == 'O'].tolist()

#Distinct columns for to find catagories
unique_list = [X[c].unique().tolist() for c in categorical_columns]

# Create a boolean mask for numerical columns
numerical_columns = X.columns[X.dtypes != 'O'].tolist()

#Encoding & Scaling objects
scaler = StandardScaler()
ohe = OneHotEncoder(categories=unique_list, sparse=False)

#Define a pipeline
pipeline  = Pipeline([("ohe_onestep", ohe.fit_transform(X[categorical_columns])),  
         ("scaler_onestep", scaler.fit_transform(X[numerical_columns])),
         MultiOutputClassifier(xgb.XGBClassifier(objective='binary:logistic'))])

# Cross-validate the model
cross_val_scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, 
                                   scoring='accuracy', cv=5)
```

But when i run the code this error appears ;
Row is;

*> pipeline  = Pipeline([("ohe_onestep", ohe.fit_transform(X[categorical_columns])),*

> 'MultiOutputClassifier' object is not iterable

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: first, you need to pass the transformers or the estimators *themselves* to the pipeline, not the result of fitting/transforming them (that would give the resultant arrays to the pipeline not the transformers, and it'd fail). Pipeline itself will be fitting/transforming. Second, since you have specific transformations to the specific columns, [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn-compose-columntransformer) is needed.

Putting these together:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

col_transformers = ColumnTransformer([
                          # name, transformer itself, columns to apply
                          ("scaler_onestep", scaler, numerical_columns),
                          ("ohe_onestep", ohe, categorical_columns)])

model = MultiOutputClassifier(xgb.XGBClassifier(objective="binary:logistic"))

pipeline = Pipeline([("preprocessing", col_transformers), ("XGB", model)])
```

Now you can do

```
cross_val_scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, 
                                   scoring="accuracy", cv=5)
```

---

As an extra, in general you could use [`make_column_selector`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_selector.html) with `dtype` option to let it infer the numericals and categoricals [as exemplified here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#columntransformer-for-heterogeneous-data).

Lastly, the reason of the error you got: `Pipeline` expects a list of tuples. You did pass tuples for the first 2 items, i.e., for `scaler` and `ohe`, but you didn't pass a `(<name>, model)` tuple as the third item; instead you gave it the model directly and it tried to iterate over it to get these names etc. and failed.

Comment: Thank you for this informative answer and the code you wrote.
You really guided me. :)